# How to delete document in content version?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

```
@RemoteAction
public static void DeletePriorties(string Rid)    {   
    ContentVersion sList =[Select id,Title,FileType,GeneratedDate__c,FilelinkedCode__c,ContentUrl,createdby.name
                            FROM ContentVersion 
                            WHERE SourceRequisitionId__c=:Rid];

    ContentVersion file= new ContentVersion();
    file.OwnerId=UserInfo.getUserId();
    file.FileLinkedCode__c=sList.FileLinkedCode__c;
    file.SourceRequisitionId__c=sList.SourceRequisitionId__c;
    file.pathOnClient=sList.pathOnClient;
    file.versionData=sList.versionData;
    file.GeneratedDate__c=sList.GeneratedDate__c;
    insert file;
    delete sList;
}
```

But I got this error:

```
 Compile Error: DML operation DELETE not allowed on ContentVersion at line 535 column 9
```

I followed this link but i Don't  KNOW HOW TO USE THIS QUERY. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm#sforce_api_objects_contentversion

Comment: You have to delete the `ContentDocument` and all its versions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In [the SFDC Objects documentation you referenced](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm#sforce_api_objects_contentversion), at the top of the page is this line:

```
create(), describeLayout(), describeSObjects(), query(), 
retrieve(), search(), update(), upsert()
```

No delete - hence a DML delete on this object is not permitted.

This makes sense because in the user interface, you can't delete a version either, only add a new one

All `ContentVersion` versions are hung under (as a child) a `ContentDocument`. The ContentDocument, if deleted, deletes all child ContentVersions

From the [SFDC Object reference documentation on ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm):

> When you delete a document, all versions of that document are deleted, including ratings, comments, and tags.

Comment: Note: delete() and undelete() features have been provided now. Please check same [documentation link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm)

Comment: @Robi -- The doc link you posted is to `ContentDocument`, not `ContentVersion` which was the subject of the OP.  One could always delete ContentDocument (that in turn, deleted all ContentVersion)

Comment: Yeah. You still can not delete individual version of a content. This idea is under consideration https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqAPAA0

Answer (score 1):

First, find the ContentDocumentIds for the versions you need to delete (when you upload a file as a ContentVersion, contentDocument record is automatically created for you). Then, all you have to do is delete the contentDocuments with those Ids.
Your SOQL query is also potentially assigning a list of records to a variable representing a single ContentVersion record, so that should be fixed unless you set this field as unique.

**Your code then becomes:**

```
@RemoteAction
public static void DeletePriorties(string Rid)    {
  List<ContentDocument> listToDelete = new List<ContentDocument>();
  List<ContentVersion> listToInsert = new List<ContentVersion>();
  for (ContentVersion conver : [
      SELECT
        id, Title, FileType, GeneratedDate__c, FilelinkedCode__c,
        ContentUrl, createdby.name, ContentDocumentId
      FROM ContentVersion
      WHERE SourceRequisitionId__c=:Rid
  ]) {
    listToDelete.add(new ContentDocument(
      Id = conver.ContentDocumentId,
    ));
    listToInsert.add(new ContentVersion(
      OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
      FileLinkedCode__c = conver.FileLinkedCode__c,
      SourceRequisitionId__c = Rid,
      pathOnClient = conver.pathOnClient,
      versionData = conver.versionData,
      GeneratedDate__c = conver.GeneratedDate__c
    ));
  }
  delete listToDelete;
  insert listToInsert;
}
```

You will probably want to add some error checking and a database savepoint in case your DMLs fail.

You can also adjust this method to accept a list of Rid strings to avoid any loops with SOQL inside:

```
@RemoteAction
public static void DeletePriorties(List<String> rids)    {
  List<ContentDocument> listToDelete = new List<ContentDocument>();
  List<ContentVersion> listToInsert = new List<ContentVersion>();
  for (ContentVersion conver : [
      SELECT
        id, Title, FileType, GeneratedDate__c, FilelinkedCode__c,
        ContentUrl, createdby.name, ContentDocumentId
      FROM ContentVersion
      WHERE SourceRequisitionId__c IN :rids
  ]) {
    listToDelete.add(new ContentDocument(
      Id = conver.ContentDocumentId,
    ));
    listToInsert.add(new ContentVersion(
      OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
      FileLinkedCode__c = conver.FileLinkedCode__c,
      SourceRequisitionId__c = conver.SourceRequisitionId__c,
      pathOnClient = conver.pathOnClient,
      versionData = conver.versionData,
      GeneratedDate__c = conver.GeneratedDate__c
    ));
  }
  delete listToDelete;
  insert listToInsert;
}
```

Good luck!